# Join the result of 2 ordered queries without losing the order (in sql)

Tags: sql, join, append

I have 2 queries, I need to have a query that outputs the result of query 1 and appends the result of query 2 after it:

query 1

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE START >= '2010-1-1'
ORDER BY START
```

query 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE START < '2010-1-1'
AND END > '2010-1-1'
ORDER BY END
```

a result could be:
01 jan 2010 - 02 jan 2010 ->from query 1
02 jan 2010 - 01 feb 2010 ->from query 1
01 nov 2009 - 10 feb 2010 ->from query 2
01 oct 2009 - 11 feb 2010 ->from query 2

In other words, first the events that have not begun on the date yet ordered by start and then the events in progress ordered by end.

I can't seem to use join as that changes the order...

Answer (score 2):

You could add dummy order by columns and `UNION` the results of both selects to return the results ordered as you like.

```
SELECT  *
        , 'Start' AS OrderBy1
        , Start AS OrderBy2
FROM    events
WHERE   START >= '2010-1-1'
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
        , 'End' AS OrderBy1
        , End AS OrderBy2
FROM    events
WHERE   START < '2010-1-1'
        AND END > '2010-1-1'
ORDER BY
        OrderBy1 DESC
        , OrderBy2
```